# Menu mobile Wordpress it's under the home

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

I'm setting up a site with wordpress, the mobile side gives me a problem the menu, when I try to open it it remains under the home page, what can I do?
The site is: www.francescoscagliola.it 
Connect with a phone to take a look and see the problem from the menu.
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website ,remove the below css and check the mobile view

```
.stretched_menu #dt-menu.dt-menu-right {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where should I go to do this? in which menù?

Comment: @daniele check in wp-content/themes/hue/css/hue.css